# Cannot create a method in a class

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ but have had some experience with java. I am trying to create a class but  when i attempt to make a new method in the class I get several error (this is my .cpp file)

```
//.cpp file
#include "Test.h"
#include "Test.h"
#include <iostream>//unresolved inclusion
using namespace std;

void speak() {

    if (happy) {//Symbol hapy could not be resolved
        cout << "Meouw!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Ssssss!" << endl;
    }
}

void Test::makeHappy() { // member decleration not found
    happy = true;//Symbol hapy could not be resolved
}

void Test::makeSad() { // member decleration not found
    happy = false;//Symbol hapy could not be resolved
}
```

I dont get any errors in my heder file but have included it just in case

```css
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

class Test {
private:
 bool happy;

public:
 void makeHappy();
 void makeSad();
 void speak();
};

#endif /* TEST_H_ */

Finally I have another .cpp file I use which also gets errors

#include <iostream>//unresolved inclusion
#include "Test.h"
#include "Test.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main() {
 Test jim;
 jim.makeHappy();//method make happy could not be resolved
 jim.speak();//method speak could not be resolved

 Test bob;
 bob.makeSad();//method make happy could not be resolved
 bob.speak();//method speak could not be resolved

 return 0;
}
This is the new error message I get when compiling

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

Sorry if this question is to open ended but I just cannot seem to find answers elsewhere.

Comment: Change to `void Test::speak() {` as done with the other methods.

Comment: General rule: Fix the first problem. Often the compiler gets confused by errors, and further errors disappear if earlier errors are fixed.

Comment: One important thing the other comments / answers are missing: Do not include the .cpp file.

Comment: Please **edit** your post and include the _exact_ error messages you are getting, not just code comments about the errors.

Comment: Also how are you getting unresolved reference errors at link time if your code supposedly doesn't compile? Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your header file Test.h:

1. happy member was named bhappy_
2. for a private member think to add a getter and setter public member functions

```html
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

class Test {
private:
 bool bhappy_;
public:
    Test() // ctor
    virtual ~Test() // dtor
public:
 void makeHappy();
 void makeSad();
 void speak();
};

#endif /* TEST_H_ */
```

this is your Test.cpp file:

1. **It's not advised to use using namespace std;**
2. Don't include your header two times

```html
//.cpp file
#include "Test.h"
#include <iostream>//unresolved inclusion

//ctor
Test::Test() : bhappy_(false)
{}

Test::~Test(){}

void Test::speak() {

    if (bhappy_) {//Symbol hapy could not be resolved
        std::cout << "Meouw!" << endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Ssssss!" << endl;
    }
}

void Test::makeHappy() {
    bhappy_ = true;//Symbol hapy could not be resolved
}

void Test::makeSad() { // member decleration not found
    bhappy_ = false;//Symbol hapy could not be resolved
}
```

This is your main function:

```
#include "Test.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Test jim;
    jim.makeHappy();//method make happy could not be resolved
    jim.speak();//method speak could not be resolved

    Test bob;
    bob.makeSad();//method make happy could not be resolved
    bob.speak();//method speak could not be resolved

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This fixed the errors except it still says symbol bhappy_ could not be resolved. On "Test::Test() : bhappy_(false)" I get the message " Member happy was not initialized in this constructor.  Also if i don't include "using namespace std" I get an error message saying symbol cout and endl could not be resolved.

Comment: look at the new edit it should fix all compile errors. good luck

Comment: I now get this error: no `void Test::makeHappy()' member function declared in class `Test'.  Also why is it not recommended to use namespace std.  I might just uninstall and reinstall my compiler if it could be a problem with that. Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score -1):

You need specify Test::speak().
Take should use this. to use class attribut. Think about getter and setter.

And finally, look C++ training, it should be usefull ^^ .

See you.